# Is it possible to override DateTime.ToString() function in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, datetime, cultureinfo

I would like to override the default behavior of the `DateTime.ToSting()` function so I can add it automatically the `CultureInfo`.

My final result is that if someone use the function like this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("g");
```

I can make it work like this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("g", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

It's a multi threaded application in **.NET 4 Framework** and I prefer not the set it on each thread.

Comment: It's a multi threaded application in .NET 4. I prefer not the set it on each thread.

Comment: You don't want to set the culture info each time? Is that where you're going?

Comment: I prefer not the set it on each thread. if it's possible to override this function it will be better.

Comment: Are you always using "en-us" as your culture?

Comment: No, but all the threads will use the same culture

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `CultureInfo` for the Current Thread, which will lead to changes you need. According MSDN, [`DateTime.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method uses formatting information derived from the current culture. For more information, see [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx).

So you can simply edit the [`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) property in thread you are using for creation other threads., and this will lead you to the behaviour you want.

MSDN example for multithreading and `AppDomains`:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

public class Info : MarshalByRefObject
{
   public void ShowCurrentCulture()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Culture of {0} in application domain {1}: {2}",
                        Thread.CurrentThread.Name,
                        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName,
                        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
   }
}

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Info inf = new Info();
      // Set the current culture to Dutch (Netherlands).
      Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "MainThread";
      CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL");
      inf.ShowCurrentCulture();

      // Create a new application domain.
       AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Domain2");
       Info inf2 = (Info) ad.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(Info).Assembly.FullName, "Info");
       inf2.ShowCurrentCulture();                       
   }
}
// The example displays the following output: 
//       Culture of MainThread in application domain ChangeCulture1.exe: nl-NL 
//       Culture of MainThread in application domain Domain2: nl-NL
```

You can try to override the usage of the method via [Microsoft Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx) or [Moles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798308.aspx) or something similar tool, but this is not really recommended.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is a sealed struct so it cannot be inherited. One way to achieve this to use Extension:

```
public static class MyDateTimeExtension
{

    public static string ToMyCulture(this DateTime dt, CultureInfo info)
    {
         ...
    }
}

DateTime timeTest = DateTime.Now;
var myTimeString = timeTest.ToMyCulture(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: This will not change the behaviour of already written classes into the application.